# C# Nested Properties initialize

Tags: c#, properties, initialization

I have the below simple declaration of nested properties (simplified):

```
public class standardMessage
{
    public messageProperties message { get; set; }
    public messageFlags flag { get; set; }
}

public class messageProperties
{
    public string messageSubject { get; set; }
    public string messageBody { get; set; }
}

public class messageFlags
{
    public Boolean flagImportant { get; set; }
    public Boolean flagPersonal { get; set; }
}
```

Upon initialization, I am trying to enter values, but seems I am missing something:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        standardMessage myMessage = new standardMessage();
        messageProperties myMsgProperties = new messageProperties();

        myMsgProperties.messageSubject = "Hey!";
        myMsgProperties.messageBody = "Howdy";

        //below code throws error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
        //MyMessage.message.messageSubject = "Greetings";
        //MyMessage.message.messageBody = "Happy weekend";

        //error - how do I print the values?
        Console.WriteLine(myMessage.message.messageSubject.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Could you please help me with the above? wither way I tried, it doesn't run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize the instance of `messageProperties` first, before accessing the instance properties

```cs
myMessage.message = new messageProperties
{
    messageBody = "Happy weekend",
    messageSubject = "Greetings"
};
```

instead of this

```cs
//below code throws error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
//MyMessage.message.messageSubject = "Greetings";
//MyMessage.message.messageBody = "Happy weekend";
```

Then you'll be able to print it out successfully

```cs
Console.WriteLine(myMessage.message.messageSubject);
```

prints

> Greetings

Another option is to initialize nested properties in constructor, like that

```cs
public class standardMessage
{
    public standardMessage()
    {
        message = new messageProperties();
        flag = new messageFlags();
    }

    public messageProperties message { get; set; }
    public messageFlags flag { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can assign the values like you want

```cs
myMessage.message.messageSubject = "Greetings";
myMessage.message.messageBody = "Happy weekend";
```

Or you can finish you snippet and set the nested property directly

```cs
standardMessage myMessage = new standardMessage();
messageProperties myMsgProperties = new messageProperties();

myMsgProperties.messageSubject = "Hey!";
myMsgProperties.messageBody = "Howdy";

myMessage.message = myMsgProperties;

Console.WriteLine(myMessage.message?.messageSubject);
```

Prints

> Hey!

Null-conditional [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) `?` will help you to avoid `NullReferenceException` if any

Comment: @Nick you are welcome, I've added more options to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the definition for your `standardMessage` class to either use inline initializers or add a default constructor (whichever works depending upon the language version you are using).

```
public class standardMessage
{
    public standardMessage()
    {
        message = new messageProperties();
        flag = new messageFlags();
    }

    public messageProperties message { get; set; } = new messageProperties();
    public messageFlags flag { get; set; } = new messageFlags();
}
```